# Trusty partman preseed is ignoring partition sizes

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, preseed

Been going round and round on this, but no matter what I do, my partition sizes are incorrect.  Using the below recipe, I get an 8 TB / partition when I should be getting 100GB.  Did something change?  I was under the impression that first line of a partition should be:

minsize priority maxsize part-type

But trust completely ignores this and does things in order regardless of my priority, such that if I reverse / and swap, I'll get an 8 TB swap partition and I REALLY don't get it.

```
d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string                         \
  boot-root ::                                            \
          1 1 1 free                                      \
                  $iflabel{ gpt }                         \
                  $reusemethod{ }                         \
                  method{ biosgrub }                      \
          .                                               \
          256 50 256 ext3                                  \
                  $primary{ } $bootable{ }                \
                  method{ format } format{ }              \
                  use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext3 }    \
                  mountpoint{ /boot }                     \
          .                                               \
          64 512 100% linux-swap                          \
                  $primary{ } method{ swap } format{ }    \
          .                                               \
          20000 30000 100000 ext4                      \
                  method{ format } format{ }              \
                  use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
                  mountpoint{ / }                         \
          .
```

I frankly am not sure what that first section is supposed to be, it's something a co-worker put in there, but removing it has no effect.

Comment: pleawse see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/340400/ubuntu-preseed-partman-gets-partition-type-and-size-wrong

Comment: I did see that in a search, but it does not answer my question.  I have my / partition last and partman continues to ignore my maxsize limit.

Comment: Do you see the 100% in this line? `64 512 100% linux-swap` I suggest you go back over it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting at.  I have 100% in my linux-swap line, and it means that swap should use 100% of my RAM size, which it does.  Then the next partition says the max size should be 100GB, but instead it uses the entire rest of the disk.  So, with this partman scripts, I should be getting a 64GB swap partition and a 100GB / partition.  Instead I get a 64GB swap and an 8TB /.  I don't see how the 100% is relevant to the question because that part is working as designed. I don't want to specify swap size, that defeats the purpose.

Comment: I'm sorry, did I misunderstand " such that if I reverse / and swap, I'll get an 8 TB swap partition and I REALLY don't get it."?

Comment: IAgain, what is your point?  I appreciate you're responding, but I wish you'd just speak plainly.  The 100% doesn't take up the entire disk when it's not the last entry because 100% on a linux-swap partition has a special meaning: 100% of RAM size, not 100% of disk.  Are you trying to say the last partition listed is going to use the entire disk regardless of what I tell it?  Are you telling me I'm not using/understanding the 100% directive properly?  What are you telling me?  The thread you linked to doesn't even mention the 100% directive.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. looks like a limitation. See: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/179880/preseed-setting-wrong-partition-size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final partition will use the whole free size of the disk. you can add an unmounted, unneeded  partition here at the end and remove it later.

Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/179880/preseed-setting-wrong-partition-size

Comment: Glad to help!!!