# Ubuntu 18.04 - debian installer (preseed) not respecting max size on partitions

Tags: system-installation, debian-installer

I am using preseed to do an unattended install of Ubuntu 18.04 using the following recipe, but it ends up with the lv_swap partition filling up the disk and it ends up with 60+GB.

How can I make the partitions respect the size described on the recipe:
1 GB /boot
20GB / (LVM)
20GB /var (LVM)
4 GB swap (LVM)
rest would be free space on LVM to be used later

> d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string      
> boot-root ::                             
> 1 1 1 free                             
> $bios_boot{ }                        
> method{ biosgrub }                   
> .                                      
> 1024 1024 1024 ext4                    
> $primary{ }                          
> $bootable{ }                         
> method{ format } format{ }           
> use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 } 
> mountpoint{ /boot }                  
> .                                      
> 20480 20480 20480 ext4                 
> $lvmok{ }                            
> method{ format } format{ }           
> use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 } 
> mountpoint{ / }                      
> lv_name{ lv_root }                   
> .                                      
> 20480 20480 20480 ext4                 
> $lvmok{ }                            
> method{ format } format{ }           
> use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 } 
> mountpoint{ /var }                   
> lv_name{ lv_var }                    
> .                                      
> 4096 4096 4096 linux-swap              
> $lvmok{ }                            
> method{ swap } format{ }             
> lv_name{ lv_swap }                   
> .

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define another partition that does not get used.  `partman` will ignore the max value on the last partition to fill the disk.

**Links**

- [Trusty partman preseed is ignoring partition sizes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/612479/trusty-partman-preseed-is-ignoring-partition-sizes)
- https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=820788
- https://serverfault.com/questions/1049610/how-do-you-use-method-keep-in-partman-auto/1062217#1062217